# User appearing in two mutually exclusive experiments in firebase a/b testing

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

In Firebase for iOS I’m running two tests (#2 and #3) with the same target action, 'do N'.

I have created an Audience "Fans" to use as a condition.
Fans = users who have done N at least once in the previous app version.

Test#2 targets 100% users in the audience "Fans".
Test#3 targets 100% users NOT in the audience "Fans".

From the [docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en) we know that users are attached to audiences permanently

> Specifically, users become permanent members of an audience after they are assigned to it.

So I would expect that users in the test#2 and test#3 do not intersect. However, bigquery shows that sometimes an event "do N" has corresponding user property as "firebase_exp_2" and "firebase_exp_3" at the same time – https://www.dropbox.com/s/2yyqcelbf8dryvc/Screenshot%202018-06-09%2017.49.33.png

How can this be possible? 
Moreover, the remote config options are not the same for these experiments. How do I know, which variant a user actually has?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you defining the "User not in audience Fans" test? AFAIK, Remote Config doesn't have any kind of "target users not in audience" capability

Comment: @ToddKerpelman I set the parameters for one test as 'includes all of' audience and for the second one as "does not include all of" audience option. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should now use user audiences in a/b test as it takes a lot of time for a user to become a part of audience. Also in your case, a user can be in no audience (and be part of test2) and then become a member of your fans (and so be part of test1). You should use user properties for a/b tests, they work faster and also you can configure a property like "times_user_have_done_N" and target users who have done it > or < than x